# How $|x|<a\implies a>0$

Tags: trigonometry, absolute-value

**The title is not exactly what I'm asking, so sorry for that.**

I was doing a problem in my mathematics text book.

[image]

It is given that $|x|<a$, I thought if $a=2$ then we can put $x=1$ but what if when $a=-2$ then too we can put $x=1$ but then $|x| \not< a$.

When we have $x=1$ and $a=2$ then we will have same expression as when $x=1$ and $a=-2$(with negative sign) because ultimately we have $a^2=4$ in both the case.

**The problem is that I don't believe that book is wrong but if book is correct then where I'm making mistake?** Kindly clear my confusion.

**What I have thought**

If $a$ is negative then $|x|<a$ will have no solution.

Domain of function $\tan^{-1}$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I would say that the book should have stated:$$|x|\lt|a|$$

Comment: The text book has put a constraint - but there is not enough context to show why or whether it is sensible. Perhaps, for example, this is the solution to a problem where $a$ is obviously positive, or is assumed to be positive.

Comment: The book is correct and you're not making any mistakes with the details of the algebra. Your confusion is just with sort of seeing what the book us saying. The book says a certain thing is ok for $a>0$. Now you notice that you could also have $a<0$. The point you're missing is this: _So what_? The book says $a>0$ is ok. You find that $a<0$ is also ok. This is no problem, because the book did _not_ say that $a<0$ is _not_ ok!

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich But sir if $a<0$ is ok then we will have no $x$ according to $|x|<a$.